Sticky Navbar Gets Lost At A Point
I'm trying to make a navbar for my website, but once I scroll past the blue section, I find the element stops sticking to the top and disappears with the other elements. How might I address this? Thank you!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Elsa Frankel | Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<nav id="navbar">
    <h1>My Name</h1>
    <div id="nav-buttons">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
        <a href="#resoucres">Resources</a>
        <a href="#consulting">Consulting</a>
    </div>
    <div id="socials">
        <a href="" id="linkedin">icon</a>
        <a href="" id="tiktok">icon</a>
        <a href="" id="email">icon</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<body>
        <div class="body-page" id="home">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="home-section" id="academic">
                    <img class="home-img" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="home-section" id="professional">
                    <img class="home-img" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body-page" id="projects">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="projects-section" id="">
                    <img class="projects-img" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="projects-section" id="">
                    <img class="projects-img" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="projects-section" id="">
                    <img class="projects-img" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body-page" id="resources">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="resources-section" id="college-students">
                    <img class="resources-img" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="resources-section" id="high-school-students">
                    <img class="resources-img" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="resources-section" id="misc">
                    <img class="resources-img" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body-page" id="consulting">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="consulting-section" id="">
                    <img class="consulting-img" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="consulting-section" id="">
                    <img class="consulting-img" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="consulting-section" id="">
                    <img class="consulting-img" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="consulting-section" id="">
                    <img class="consulting-img" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@100..900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* Header Height */
    bottom: 0px; /* Footer Height */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Outfit", sans-serif;
}

nav {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    position: sticky;
    height: 9%;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #4d4d4d;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 2em;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

#nav-buttons a{
    margin: 0 0.7em;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.body-page {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
}

#home {
    background-color: blue;
}

I tried taking the navbar out of the body section and changing the position of body-page elements.

Please first correct your HTML, you have put elements between the head and the body, using a validator can be helpful.

still having the same issue unfortunately

You can use position fixed and give an extra margin to the first element, as using position fixed will hide part of the first element behind the fixed element.

First as @A Haworth said you can't put elements between your head and body (ie your nav element here) (made a snipet to corrected it).

Use position fixed for your nav instead of position sticky. Also why your body is position absolute?

@Mehdi you last comment is incorrect. position: fixed should not be used here. position: fixed will always move the navbar out of the flow. That way it will obscure the content from the start on. position: stickyis the correct use.position: absolute` makes no sense but will also not hurt.

@Mehdi, also never fix incorrect markup of anyone as this could alter the questions and solve the issue. Always copy the code as it is to a snippet. You may reduce code to make it minimal but as said you should never fix issues with the code yourself.

@tacoshy noted for position fixed I added this comment as I have seen position fixed added many times on nav bar essentialy after scrolling. You are as well correct for not fixing incorrect markup

@Mehdi that's an old JS implementation to switch position: static to position: fixed when the onscroll event is triggered. But that's exactly what position: sticky does as well. It's just a rather new method. I think it was only fully supported after the deprecation of IE and should have been around since 2017 or so.

@tacoshy you are right never looked deeply into position sticky but it can do exactly what we can do with adding  fixed position with scroll. Below is an example link. And you know what just used the old way in one of my website...will consider it from now. thks for the info.

There's something wrong in the HTML structure as I see, but the main issue is about positioning in CSS:
nav should be inside body and possibly wrapped into a header.
Try changing the height of .body-page to height: 100vh instead of 100% and also remove absolute property from your body.
body {
    font-family: "Outfit", sans-serif;
}

.body-page {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
}

Here's a CodePen link to see how these adjustments might work in action: https://codepen.io/giovannimanetti11/pen/zYQrMEN

instead of linking to a codepen you should use a [repro] directly in the question/answer.
